# Overwriting result with for loop in R

Tags: r

I have a number of csv files and my goal is to find the number of complete cases for a file or set of files given by id argument. My function should return a data frame with column id specifying the file and column obs giving the number of complete cases for this id. However, my function overwrites the previous value of nobs in each loop and the resulting data frame gives me only its last value. Do you have any idea how to get the value of nobs for each value of id?

```
  myfunction<-function(id=1:20) {
  files<-list.files(pattern="*.csv")
  myfiles = do.call(rbind, lapply(files, function(x) read.csv(x,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))  

   for (i in id) {  
   good<-complete.cases(myfiles)
   newframe<-myfiles[good,]
   cases<-newframe[newframe$ID %in% i,]
   nobs<-nrow(cases)  
  }
  clean<-data.frame(id,nobs)
  clean
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the expected output? Also, read about [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I tried to explain better in my post.

Comment: I don't know `R`, but you need to add `nobs` to a list or something similar, to be able to use that list as an argument to your `data.frame` function.

Answer (score 0):

We can do all inside `lapply()`, something like below (not tested):

```
myfunction <- function(id = 1:20) {
  files <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv")[id]

  do.call(rbind,
          lapply(files, function(x){
            df <- read.csv(x,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
            df <- df[complete.cases(df), ]
            data.frame(ID=x,nobs=nrow(df))
            }
            )
          )  
}
```

Comment: The function gives the complete cases for each file and not for the files specified in the argument id of the function. So id should be incorporated in the function somehow.(id is also a column in each file so id=1 means file 1 etc.)

Comment: @SimonaAleksandrovaAtanasova we just need to subset `files` object, post updated.

Comment: This gives, however, again a data frame with 36 rows, where the result from each loop is repeated 6 times (6 loops x 6 values)

Comment: @SimonaAleksandrovaAtanasova What happens when you do `myfunction(id = 1:2)`?

Comment: I found the solution though, thanks for the help!! I just had the initialize nobs as a vector.